# addChildViewController view not displaying

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Using storyboards I am trying to overlay a `UIViewController` on top of a current `View`.

In my `FirstViewController` I import the `SecondViewController.h` and then run the following in the `viewDidLoad` method

```
SecondViewController *overlay = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
overlay.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:overlay];
[self.view addSubview:overlay.view];
[overlay didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:overlay.view];
```

In my `SecondViewController.h` `viewDidLoad` method I have an output to `NSLog` which is getting displayed in the console when I run the app, however the second view is not being display on top of the first. So the `SecondViewController` is getting added but not displayed. What is it am I missing?

Essentially I want the `SecondViewController` to have transparent background so I can do a fancy alert message that displays information, and you can still see the `FirstViewController` behind it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the identifier of secondViewController and the use the simple code:

```
secondViewController *overlay = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
overlay.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200);
[self.view addSubview:overlay.view];
```

In my case the identifier is same as class name that is "secondViewController".

Comment: Thanks. So obvious. A case of coding blindness.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer.